# elastic query to get events where corresponding pair is missing

Tags: elasticsearch

I have records of transaction which follow following lifecycle.

- Event when transaction is received [RCVD]
- Event when transaction gets pending for execution [PNDG]  (OPTIONAL step)
- Event when it gets executed [SENT]

Following are the 7 sample events in the index:

```
{trxID: 1, status:RCVD}
{trxID: 2, status:RCVD}
{trxID: 3, status:RCVD}
{trxID: 2, status:PNDG}
{trxID: 3, status:PNDG}
{trxID: 1, status:SENT}
{trxID: 2, status:SENT}
```

I need to find all the transactions  which went to pending state but not executed yet. In other word there should be **PNDG** status for transaction but not **SENT**.
I am trying not to do it at java layer.

I did an aggregation on trxID, and then I did sub aggregation on status.
Then I cannot figure out how to get those records where bucket has only PNDG  in sub-aggregation. I am not sure if I am thinking in right direction.

The result I am expecting is **trxID 3** because for this transaction ,we got **PNDG** status but did not get **SENT** yet. On the other hand **TrxUD 1** should not be reported as it never went to **PNDG** (pending) state irrespective of if **SENT** status is reported of not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use count of status under a transaction id.

```
GET index24/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "transactionId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "trxID",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "status": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "status.keyword",
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "status.keyword"
          }
        },
        "my_bucketselector": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "statusCount": "count"
            },
            "script": "params.statusCount==1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "transactionId" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 4,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "count" : {
            "value" : 1
          },
          "status" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "PNDG",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

EDIT 1:
I have tried with below :-
   Get max date for a transaction id and then get date under pending . If both dates are same then pending is the last status

Data:

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "aYCs0m0BD5PlkoxXxO36",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "trxID" : 1,
          "status" : "RCVD",
          "date" : "2019-10-15T12:00:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "aoCs0m0BD5PlkoxX7e35",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "trxID" : 1,
          "status" : "PNDG",
          "date" : "2019-10-15T12:01:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "a4Ct0m0BD5PlkoxXCO06",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "trxID" : 1,
          "status" : "SENT",
          "date" : "2019-10-15T12:02:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bICt0m0BD5PlkoxXQe0Y",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "trxID" : 2,
          "status" : "RCVD",
          "date" : "2019-10-15T12:00:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bYCt0m0BD5PlkoxXZO2x",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "trxID" : 2,
          "status" : "PNDG",
          "date" : "2019-10-15T12:01:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "boCt0m0BD5PlkoxXju1H",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "trxID" : 3,
          "status" : "RCVD",
          "date" : "2019-10-15T12:00:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index24",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "b4Ct0m0BD5PlkoxXou0-",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "trxID" : 3,
          "status" : "SENT",
          "date" : "2019-10-15T12:01:00"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
GET index24/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "transactionId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "trxID",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "maxDate": {
          "max": {
            "field": "date"  ---> get max date under transactions
          }
        },
        "pending_status": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "status.keyword": "PNDG" ---> filter for pending
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filtered_maxdate": {
              "max": {
                "field": "date"    --> get date under pending
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "buckets_latest_status_pending": { -->filter if max date==pending date
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "filtereddate": "pending_status>filtered_maxdate",
              "maxDate": "maxDate"
            },
            "script": "params.filtereddate==params.maxDate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "transactionId" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 2,  --> only transaction id 2 is returned
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "pending_status" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "filtered_maxdate" : {
              "value" : 1.57114086E12,
              "value_as_string" : "2019-10-15T12:01:00.000Z"
            }
          },
          "maxDate" : {
            "value" : 1.57114086E12,
            "value_as_string" : "2019-10-15T12:01:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Jaspreet. Your solution except making params.statusCount < 3, cover my original requirement. Though I am sorry I missed on crucial detail where PNDG status is optional. So I want to monitor only when there is PNDG status for trx. So I guess considering that, I can't rely on just counting status. I have update my question.

Comment: @Shishal does document has a unique date field along with status?

Comment: @Shishal I have added an update under EDIT1, have a check

Comment: Glad could be of help

Answer (score 0):

> I did an aggregation on trxID, and then I did sub aggregation on status.

That's a great start !!!

Now, you can leverage the [`bucket_selector` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) in order to surface only the transactions which have only 1 or 2 documents, i.e. the script condition `params.eventCount < 3` makes sure to catch all buckets that have `RCVD` and/or `PNDG` documents but no `SENT` documents:

```
POST events/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "trx": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "trxID",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "status.keyword"
          }
        },
        "not_sent": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "eventCount": "count"
            },
            "script": "params.eventCount < 3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your case, this would yield this, i.e. only event with `trxID = 3`:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "trx" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 3,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "count" : {
            "value" : 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank You Val. Its cover 90% of my usecase. Though I am sorry ,I missed one critical detail that PNDG status is optional. and I am only interested in monitoring trx when trx goes to PNDG status. I have updated the question.

Comment: Then, you can simply make the condition be `params.eventCount == 2` since PNDG can only be present after RCVD.

Comment: If I make it 2 then I will report Trx1 as well which I don't want.

Comment: No it won't since Trx1 has three documents in its bucket. eventCount = 2 really means that the transaction is in PNDG status right now

Comment: Actually If you check, trx 1 have 2 document, Since PNDG is optional, so it went FROM RCVD to SENT directly.